# How to remove words from a string in specific pattern and keep the first number

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a bunch of strings in a form like `d.d$ word1 word2 word3`. Word 2 and 3 could be in string or not. For example, I have these strings:

```
1.0% SELLING
3.2% AND 1.0% AND 1.2%
1.0% SOLD PRICE
1.2% PURCHASE PRICE FINAL
2.5% AND 1.0%
1.0% SELLING 2.0% people
```

What I am willing to do is that only for string 1, 3, 4 I only keep **1.0%** **1.0%** **1.2%**
What I tried to do is:

```
gsub("(\\d\\.\\d%) \\w+ ((?:\\w+)?)+", "\\1",x)
```

And the reason I used the above pattern is:

```
(\\d\\.\\d%) ....> capturing the number part
\\w+ .....> first word
((?:\\w+)?)+  .....> second and other words (optional and in no-capturing group)
```

(for some reason \s doesn't work for me properly in some cases and it's captured as s! so I use space in between the words)

The expected result should look like:

```
1.0%
3.2% AND 1.0% AND 1.2%
1.0%
1.2%
2.5% AND 1.0%
1.0% SELLING 2.0% people
```

**The code should only change strings that follow this pattern: `d.d% (rest of the string are only words and not a number)`** (that's why 1.0% SELLING 2.0% people hasn't been changed)

However, this code only works for 2 words and for 1 or 3 words it doesn't work. Please advise how I can fix this?

Comment: @RonakShah I added the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
sub('^(\\d+\\.\\d+%)(?:\\s+\\w+)*$', '\\1', x, perl=TRUE)
stringr::str_replace(x, '^(\\d+\\.\\d+%)(?:\\s+\\w+)*$', '\\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mxS0AP/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+\.\d+%)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more digits, `.`, one or more digits and a `%` sign
- `(?:\s+\w+)*` - zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespace chars and then one or more word chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/rhC4EA):

```r
x <- c("1.0% SELLING","3.2% AND 1.0% AND 1.2%","1.0% SOLD PRICE","1.2% PURCHASE PRICE FINAL","2.5% AND 1.0%","1.0% SELLING 2.0% people")
sub('^(\\d+\\.\\d+%)(?:\\s+\\w+)*$', '\\1', x, perl=TRUE)
library(stringr)
stringr::str_replace(x, '^(\\d+\\.\\d+%)(?:\\s+\\w+)*$', '\\1')
```

Both output

```r
[1] "1.0%"                     "3.2% AND 1.0% AND 1.2%"  
[3] "1.0%"                     "1.2%"                    
[5] "2.5% AND 1.0%"            "1.0% SELLING 2.0% people"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the numbers from the string and replace only those numbers who have only single digit in it.

```
tmp <- stringr::str_extract_all(x, '\\d+\\.\\d+%')
x[lengths(tmp) == 1] <- unlist(tmp[lengths(tmp) == 1])
x

#[1] "1.0%"      "3.2% AND 1.0% AND 1.2%"   "1.0%"                    
#[4] "1.2%"      "2.5% AND 1.0%"            "1.0% SELLING 2.0% people"
```

Comment: I am sure this is a valid solution, but the problem is that each of these strings is in one cell of a data frame and I want to do the replacement in the same cell. I think `sapply` returns it in a form of a separate list. right?

Comment: No, the replacement will happen in the same cell because we are using `collapse` here.

Comment: Sorry, I guess this doesn't answer my question. What I am looking for is only a code that changes a pattern like `number.number% word word.... (the rest should be word)`. what you provided will change a string like `"1.0% SELLING 2.0% people"` to `"1.0% AND 2.0%"` which I don't want this to happen. Because in that case, it will change other strings

Comment: Then what would you like `"1.0% SELLING 2.0% people"` change to? Maybe you should update your post and provide a better example since my answer gives the expected answer you have shown.

Comment: then `"1.0% SELLING 2.0% people"` shouldn't change at all. I want the code only changes strings that are in the form of `d.d% (rest of string only words)`.

Comment: I added one more example for more clarification

Comment: @Roozbeh_you Check if the updated answer works for your case.

Comment: @ The updated solution is extracting numbers correctly; however, it provides "NA" for strings that do not match. As I explained above and shown in the example result the expected result is 
`1.0%


3.2% AND 1.0% AND 1.2%


1.0%


1.2%


2.5% AND 1.0%


1.0% SELLING 2.0% people`

. Here is the result when I run your code: `"1.0%" NA     "1.0%" "1.2%" NA     NA `.Sorry, I understand you got frustrated, but unfortunately, the result of the code doesn't match the expected result I showed in question

Comment: How is that possible? Are you sure? We are not changing those values which have more than 1 digits in them. Can you provide `dput(x)` that you are using?